Dieser eine (Einsatz)
What does it mean?
Here's the context: "Dieser eine Einsatz letzte Nacht - wir sind zu diesem Haus, es war nach Mitternacht, kalt, heftiger Regen, das Wasser stand uns bis zur Brust, dann haben wir dieses zwei Jahre alte Kind durch das Fenster rausgeholt, zusammen mit der schwangeren Mutter und dem Vater"
Source: https://www.tagesschau.de/ausland/amerika/hurrikan-milton-aufraeumarbeiten-100.html
Edit: I did a bit of Googling and came across an explanation: https://www.reddit.com/r/German/comments/v0f2px/whats_going_on_with_dieser_eine_structure/

What exactly is your question? As it stands, this unfortunately looks to be purely a translation request that is likely to be closed.

In particular, which part are you confused about, the "Dieser eine", "Einsatz" or the two in combination? I gather that "Einsatz" in this case is used as military, police or fire service jargon, but you didn't say who was talking so it's hard to be sure. If so, a dictionary will tell you it can be translated as "mission", "operation" or "deployment".

I fully understand the entire article, except for "Dieser eine Einsatz". It makes no sense both on its own and in the context we see it within.

I’m voting to close this question because the news snippet, linked in the question, contains the original, am.-english Phrase ("Last night, that rescue - …) at 2:01 ff.

Im Original wurde "that" in "that rescue" hörbar betont. "Dieser eine" ist ebenfalls ein Art von Betonung, die schriftlich besser rüberkommt. Im Englischen würde ein wörtliche Rückübersetzung auch gut passen: "this one rescue" .

You know how people say e.g.of music, "I'm pretty good at playing the harp, but there's this one etude that I could never quite master"?
This German construction means exactly the same.

Bzw. "Last night, that rescue - …", wie man, bevor der Übersetzer einsetzt, gut hören kann.

"Einsatz" is (i) the start of an instrument in an orchestra at a scheduled time, as in "Die Pauken setzen dröhnend ein...", "Der Einsatz der Geigen im zweiten Takt des vierten Satzes..." (ii) the participation of a  player in some team sports as in "Der Einsatz Gerd Müllers in der zeiten Halbzeit...." (iii) a leaping-into-action of some police, rescue, firefighters or military squadron. In this context it's obviously a rescue team that is engaged in helping victims in a flooded area. The text starts with an incomplete sentence that is truncated as to indicate the speaker is overwhelmed by feelings and (at that moment) incapable of constructing full sentences.

If you want to be overly pedantic you could call it a parenthesis. This is to - hear, hear - put some related but otherwise unconnected phrase into a sentence, interrupting its normal structure. Here's the catch - this is possible at the beginning too!
Think of your example sentence as a story being told:

We went to the house, it rained, ....

Now, this story needs a headline, which sums it up:

This one call last night!

This is what is done here. In addition the device is also a means to mimick spoken language. When we speak, we don't do it always in complete and well-formed sentences (like in writing) but often use stand-alone part-sentences or phrases. Here spoken language is stylistically emulated tp further the impression of a story told instead of a story reported.
